# Using Git Tags as a condition for stages

Tags: git, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I try to make an "opt-in" button for one of my stages. My first stage is running every time, the second stage is just running when there is a specific git tag.
So far, I tried this syntax here, but everytime, when I push my new tags, it wont be triggerd as well.

```
condition: startsWith(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/BuildAndInstall')
```

In this case, the stage is only running when there is a git tag whitch is called 'BuildandInstall'
Maybe, you'll find my mistake or wether is is possible or not

Comment: May I know if you want to this condition for the specify tag `BuildAndInstall` and **all new added** tag?

Comment: Hi, I got an solution in couple days. I work with grep command and checking commit message. I will show the solution here!

Comment: I am glad that you have resolved your question. Thanks for sharing you solution here, looking forward for your solution.  This can be beneficial to other community members reading the answer, avoid spending a lot of time on a post that already has an answer. Thanks.